# Python Clustering Algorithms

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, dbscan

I've been looking around scipy and sklearn for clustering algorithms for a particular problem I have. I need some way of characterizing a population of N particles into k groups, where k is not necessarily know, and in addition to this, no a priori linking lengths are known (similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891645/clustering-problem)).

I've tried kmeans, which works well if you ***know*** how many clusters you want. I've tried dbscan, which does poorly unless you ***tell*** it a characteristic length scale on which to stop looking (or start looking) for clusters. The problem is, I have potentially thousands of these clusters of particles, and I cannot spend the time to tell kmeans/dbscan algorithms what they should go off of.

Here is an example of what dbscan find:
[image: dbscanfail]

You can see that there really are two separate populations here, though adjusting the epsilon factor (the max. distance between neighboring clusters parameter), I simply cannot get it to see those two populations of particles.

Is there any other algorithms which would work here? I'm looking for minimal information upfront - in other words, I'd like the algorithm to be able to make "smart" decisions about what could constitute a separate cluster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found one that requires NO a priori information/guesses and does very well for what I'm asking it to do. It's called [Mean Shift](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html#sklearn.cluster.MeanShift) and is located in [SciKit-Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html). It's also relatively quick (compared to other algorithms like Affinity Propagation).

Here's an example of what it gives:

[image: MeanShiftResults]

I also want to point out that in the documentation is states that it may not scale well.

Comment: Depending on the Mean Shift kernel you choose you can speed it up a bit. Here is a decent post describing some optimizations you can use to make mean shift more scalable. http://sociograph.blogspot.com/2011/11/accessible-introduction-to-mean-shift.html

Comment: MeanShift requires `bandwidth` as input, does not sound like "NO a priori" information to me?

Comment: The particular implementation chooses one for you if you do not supply one. Most importantly, it does not require a choice to be made regarding the number of clusters.

Answer (score 3):

- When using DBSCAN it can be helpful to scale/normalize data or
  distances beforehand, so that estimation of epsilon will be relative.
- There is a implementation of DBSCAN - I think its the one
  Anony-Mousse somewhere denoted as 'floating around' - , which comes
  with a epsilon estimator function. It works, as long as its not fed
  with large datasets.
- There are several [incomplete versions](https://github.com/FredrikAppelros/scikit-learn/blob/addb81b83683e218cc5dd0be9aed929d8b979685/sklearn/cluster/optics_.py) of OPTICS at github. Maybe
  you can find one to adapt it for your purpose. Still
  trying to figure out myself, which effect minPts has, using one and
  the same extraction method.
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try a minimum spanning tree (zahn algorithm) and then remove the longest edge similar to alpha shapes. I used it with a delaunay triangulation and a concave hull:http://www.phpdevpad.de/geofence. You can also try a hierarchical cluster for example clusterfck.

Comment: clusterfck is a js library with k-means and a hierarchical cluster. It compute the nearest-neighbor.

Answer (score 1):

Your plot indicates that you chose the `minPts` parameter *way* too small.

Have a look at OPTICS, which does no longer need the epsilon parameter of DBSCAN.

Comment: Yea, for this picture what you say is true - I've played around with both the minpoints and epsilon, to no avail. I'll check out OPTICS. Do you have a reference?

Comment: It's on Wikipedia, and included in ELKI.

Comment: Thanks - I was really hoping for a python function/library instead of Java.

Comment: I have seen a python version of it, but that was badly broken; it was in fact doing DBSCAN again, not OPTICS.